# add activity to facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, android-activity

1. I have a Facebook app, and want to post user activity.
   How do I do it in an web app - what are the methods and API? (not for web site, as facebook documentation in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ is for web sites).
2. Do i have to create a new html page for each user activity I want to post? Wouldn't it create millions of pages, or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found Yan has given a nice detail about this thought. Can you give a try, I am succeed on his suggestion.

Here is the link

http://ian.tresman.co.uk/how-add-facebook-page-activity-post-rss-feed-web-page.htm

Marshal
http://coronabd.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a generic aspx page to represent an activity. The Open Graph object's url redirects to the same page.